# objectCategory for domain

Tags: active-directory

We saw how objectCategory for domain controller can be used for querying all the DCs within the Forest.
Is there a similar way to iterate through all the available Domains ?

I currently use WinNT provider.

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
foreach (DirectoryEntry child in de.Children)
{
    if (child.SchemaClassName == "Domain")
    {
        domainList.Add(child.Name);
    }
    child.Dispose();
}
```

This is how I am iterating through the Domains. However, it would be nice if I get some hint as to how the DirectorySercher can be set for querying the Domains.

Comment: `I currently use WinNT provider.` Why? There is already a base class library for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

I am not aware of any class library which does the job as explained.
Alos, the above stuff stops working (doesn't return any domains) when teh SMB1 is disabled/removed. Belive me, have followed al the ways of disabling/removing teh SMB1 feature from my 2016 server. Again, I dodnt understand the link between the WnNT provider and the SMB1 stuff.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain